# Why the first call to the Round(Double) method with a value of 11.5 returns 11 instead of 12?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point

According to the MSDN article found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy.aspx the floating-point value .1 has no finite binary representation, the first call to the Round(Double) method with a value of 11.5 returns 11 instead of 12.
I can't clearly understand, why does it happen?

Comment: @Oded What version of .NET are you using? This note is not specified in .NET 3.0 and older

Comment: @AnthonyShaw: It's in the documentation for 4.0, but it of course applies to all versions (and any other platform using the standard floating point types).

Comment: @Guffa- Alright, I wasn't sure since I wasn't find that particular note on the documentation for 2.0 and 3.0, but it was there for 3.5 and 4.0, just made me wonder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first call isn't *really* using 11.5. It's using a value *slightly less than* 11.5 due to an accumulation of errors from adding 0.1 repeatedly. Here's the output if you use my [`DoubleConverter.ToExactString`](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) to show the exact values being passed in:

```
11.0999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375 --> 11
11.199999999999999289457264239899814128875732421875 --> 11
11.2999999999999989341858963598497211933135986328125 --> 11
11.39999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375 --> 11
11.4999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 --> 11
11.599999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625 --> 12

11.5 --> 12
```

At that point, all the results make sense.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to make some tests here.

Answer (score 6):

Doubles are not usually completely exact. So it might be that your value is rather something like 11.4999999999999998, and that value should clearly be rounded down to 11.

Also, note that the default rounding method for Round is *Bankers rounding* meaning that 11.5 will be rounded to 12, but 12.5 will also be rounded to 12 (for midpoint values, it's rounded towards the nearest even number, and not the highest one.